# How could I simplify this code? JavaScript + css3

Tags: javascript, css, mouseover, simplify, mouseout

I'm fairly new to programming and still getting the hang of programming logic. I've wasted a few hours trying to simplify this code but no cigar. Given the fact that the base of programming is to simplify tasks, how could I make the following code shorter?

```html
var card1 = document.getElementById('card1');
var card2 = document.getElementById('card2');
var card3 = document.getElementById('card3');
var card4 = document.getElementById('card4');

// card 1
card1.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    card2.classList.add('blur');
    card3.classList.add('blur');
    card4.classList.add('blur');
})

card1.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    card2.classList.remove('blur');
    card3.classList.remove('blur');
    card4.classList.remove('blur');
})

// card 2
card2.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    card1.classList.add('blur');
    card3.classList.add('blur');
    card4.classList.add('blur');
})

card2.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    card1.classList.remove('blur');
    card3.classList.remove('blur');
    card4.classList.remove('blur');
})

// card 3
card3.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    card1.classList.add('blur');
    card2.classList.add('blur');
    card4.classList.add('blur');
})

card3.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    card1.classList.remove('blur');
    card2.classList.remove('blur');
    card4.classList.remove('blur');
})

// card 4
card4.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    card1.classList.add('blur');
    card2.classList.add('blur');
    card3.classList.add('blur');
})

card4.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    card1.classList.remove('blur');
    card2.classList.remove('blur');
    card3.classList.remove('blur');
})
```

Thanks in advance,
Thiago

EDIT: I was eventually able to come up with something, based on @CertainPerformance's answer, that met my needs:

```html
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.modalidade__card');
const cardsArray = Array.apply(null, cards);
for (let i = 0; i < cardsArray.length; i++) {
    cardsArray[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
        for (let c = 0; c < cardsArray.length; c++) {
            cardsArray[c].classList.add('blur');
        };
        e.target.classList.remove('blur');
    });
    cardsArray[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
        for (let c = 0; c < cardsArray.length; c++) {
            if (cardsArray[c].classList.contains('blur')) {
                cardsArray[c].classList.remove('blur');
            };
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: first improvement ,  you can add your  objects to a collection and then you may  use lambas to operate, e.g, `var cards = [card1,card2,card3,card4];`  , then in your functions you can use `cards.filter(currentCard => currentCard != card1  ).forEach(filteredCard => { filteredCard.classList.add('blur') } );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use classes instead of IDs to get a collection of all cards. Then you can use event delegation on the *container* of all the cards. When one of the cards is entered, loop over the collection and blur the rest. When one of the cards is left, loop over the collection and remove the blur:

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
container.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('.card')) {
    for (const card of cards) {
      card.classList.add('blur');
    }
    e.target.classList.remove('blur');
  }
});
container.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('.card')) {
    for (const card of cards) {
      card.classList.remove('blur');
    }
  }
});
```

Note that for event delegation to work, you have to use an event that bubbles - `mouseover` and `mouseout` bubble, but `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` don't. (Or you could iterate over each card and add a listener to each with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`)

Comment: Thanks for replying! It sorta worked. If I hover on the middle of the card, it doesn't work. However, if I hover it near its borders, it works. The card has inner padding. And the card area that triggers the function is precisely where the padding is. So, I'm guessing the e.target is being replaced by some other element in my html code when I hover the middle area. I could add a transparent element on top of the cards to serve as the target. But your solution is awesome. I was more interested in ways of solving this. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: The listener should trigger as soon as the mouse enters one of the cards - after the mouse has gone past the border, there shouldn't be any changes until the mouse exits a border again.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why this is happening. I'm still trying to figure it out :( thanks again!

Comment: I figured it out what's wrong. I added a `console.log(e.target)` inside the function to see what's what. The target is being replaced by the other elements inside of the cards, then the `mouseout` function gets triggered. Any ideas?

Comment: @thiagopg84 If the target is getting replaced dynamically, it sounds like there's some code missing from the question that's essential to see for the cause to be discoverable

Answer (score 2):

You could use the css [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo-selector instead of javascript.

```css
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 8px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

li {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.cards:hover > * {
  filter: blur(5px);
  transition: filter .1s;
}

.cards > * {
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 8px;
  background: bisque;
}

.cards > *:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cards">
  <li>Card 1</li>
  <li>Card 2</li>
  <li>Card 3</li>
  <li>Card 4</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: OP wants to do something to the elements which *aren't* hovered, while one of the other ones *is* being hovered, so I don't think `:hover` will work

Comment: Ah. Right. I misread the intent. But you could still do this with a :hover and a parent or sibling selector.

Comment: You can't go backwards with CSS though. Eg while you could do `.card:hover ~ .card` (applying rule to those after the hovered card), you can't do `.card ~ .card:hover` and apply the rule to the ones behind the hovered card

Comment: But you could have a container that applies the effect to everything and a more specific selector for the hovered item. I’m going to switch to the computer and put up an example. I’m pretty sure this can be done purely via css.

Comment: @rayhatfield CertainPerformance is right, it can't be done with CSS alone. There has to be some JavaScript to allow the required states needed for the logic.

Comment: @rayhatfield well... `.cards:hover > *` isn't _quite_ the same as "only when one of the cards is hovered". You don't have to hover over any of the cards in order for that selector to activate.

Comment: @rayhatfield you can hover the parent there in the margin between each of the cards quite easily without hovering any one of them. It's a cute hack but ultimately a fully correct solution restricts the possible layouts for your cards, unlike a solution that uses JavaScript.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Fair enough. There's not enough information in OP's post to determine whether javascript is necessary to solve his problem, and until there's a specific need for it I'd be inclined to use pure css. If OP wants to elaborate I can update or delete my answer (which probably won't be necessary, because [CertainPerformance's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61134322/636077) is a pretty solid js solution).

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't resist to edit your snippet. I have added pointer events so that the problem pointed by Parick Roberts is solved. Good answer, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, @vals. That crossed my mind but it was late and I didn't feel like chasing it any further.

Answer (score 0):

For example, we can

```
var card1 = document.getElementById('card1');
var card2 = document.getElementById('card2');
var card3 = document.getElementById('card3');
var card4 = document.getElementById('card4');

var mouseenter = function(){
    if(this != card1) card1.classList.add('blur');
    if(this != card2) card2.classList.add('blur');
    if(this != card3) card3.classList.add('blur');
    if(this != card4) card4.classList.add('blur');
};
var mouseleave = function(){
    if(this != card1) card1.classList.remove('blur');
    if(this != card2) card2.classList.remove('blur');
    if(this != card3) card3.classList.remove('blur');
    if(this != card4) card4.classList.remove('blur');
};

card1.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseenter);
card1.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseleave);
card2.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseenter);
card2.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseleave);
card3.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseenter);
card3.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseleave);
card4.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseenter);
card4.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseleave);
```

Comment: Sure this simplifies the existing code, but it doesn't remove unnecessary repetition. An ideal solution would not have to repeat the same lines of code for each of the four cards.

Comment: Thanks, Derek! That's a very nice solution and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way

```js
const card1 = document.getElementById("card1"),
  card2 = document.getElementById("card2"),
  card3 = document.getElementById("card3"),
  card4 = document.getElementById("card4");

// onMouse Effect
const onMouse = (ele, type = "enter") => {
  ele.forEach((item) =>
    type === "enter"
      ? item.classList.add("blur")
      : item.classList.remove("blur")
  );
};
// Card 1
card1.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => onMouse([card2, card3, card4]));
card1.addEventListener("mouseleave", () =>
  onMouse([card2, card3, card4], "leave")
);
// Card 2
card2.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => onMouse([card1, card3, card4]));
card2.addEventListener("mouseleave", () =>
  onMouse([card1, card3, card4], "leave")
);
// Card 3
card3.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => onMouse([card2, card1, card4]));
card3.addEventListener("mouseleave", () =>
  onMouse([card2, card1, card4], "leave")
);
// Card 4
card4.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => onMouse([card2, card3, card1]));
card4.addEventListener("mouseleave", () =>
  onMouse([card2, card3, card1], "leave")
);
```

```css
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.blur h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: #111 0 0 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="p-5 m-5 text-center bg-primary cursor-pointer" id="card1">
        <h1>Card 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="p-5 m-5 text-center bg-primary cursor-pointer" id="card2">
        <h1>Card 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="p-5 m-5 text-center bg-primary cursor-pointer" id="card3">
        <h1>Card 3</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="p-5 m-5 text-center bg-primary cursor-pointer" id="card4">
        <h1>Card 4</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```